# How to collect Active X controls in the MFC dialog

Tags: com, mfc, activex, visual-c++

I know we can enumerate the windows controls with in the dialog and using the callback we can collect the windows controls.

I am looking for specific way to filtering out the controls based on interface implementation. For example, If the Active-X controls derives from interface IDataControl, I want that to add to my interest collection list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the generic process to get the ole/active-x controls inside the dialog.

1. Do EnumWindows with the callback
2. In the callback, attach the windows handle to CWnd
3. Try to get IUnknown pointer for the control CWnd::GetControlUnknown
    Tips: [How to detect whether a control is standard or active-x control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2536165/how-to-detect-whether-a-control-is-standard-or-active-x-control)
4. If returned IUnknown is not null, do queryInterface for IDataControl.
5. If IDataControl instance not null, add to collection