# How to detect whether a control is standard or active-x control?

Tags: mfc, winapi, activex, visual-c++

In MFC Application, how can we differentiate whether a control is a standard control like CComboBox  or it is an custom active-x control?

Comment: What is a control in the context of this question? A MFC class? an HWND? Some thing you saw drawn on the surface of another window?

Comment: How could you *not* know??  You created it.

Comment: @Chris Becke, @nobugz,  I basically enumerate and fetch the controls inside the window. Some of them are data  controls. thanks fretje.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`CWnd::GetControlUnknown`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6fde5b3k%28v=VS.80%29.aspx):

> ### Return Value
>
> A pointer to the [IUnknown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680509(v=VS.80).aspx) interface of
>   the OLE control represented by this
>   **CWnd** object. If this object does not
>   represent an OLE control, the return
>   value is **NULL**.

Comment: This will do. I could enumerate and fetch the control and get the IUnknown pointer. Then I try to get my interface.